How to convert my files into an URL in reactJS?
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaAngleLeft, FaAngleRight, FaRegPaperPlane } from 
"react-icons/fa6";
import { FileUpload, ParentInfo, StudentInfo } from "..";
import "./multistepForm.css";

const MultistepForm = () => {
const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
stdName: "",
stdMiddleName: "",
stdSurname: "",
stdGender: "",
stdPOB: "",
stdDOB: "",
fatherName: "",
motherName: "",
gradeLevel: "",
grade: "",
// Parent Info
prtName: "",
prtMiddleName: "",
prtSurname: "",
prtNational: "",
prtCountry: "",
prtState: "",
prtCity: "",
prtEmail: "",
prtPhone: "",
prtIDType: "",
prtIDNum: "",
// Files
prtIDImg: "",
stdTranscript: "",
stdImg: "",
});
function next() {
setStep((i) => {
  if (i >= FormHeaders.length - 1) return i;
  return i + 1;
});
}
function back() {
setStep((i) => {
  if (i <= 0) return i;
  return i - 1;
});
}
function onSubmit(e: FormEvent) {
e.preventDefault();
if (step !== FormHeaders.length - 1) return next();
alert("Submission completed");
}
const FormHeaders = [
"Student Information",
"Parent Information",
"Upload Files",
];

const StepDisplay = () => {
if (step === 0) {
  return <StudentInfo formData={formData} setFormData= 
{setFormData} />;
} else if (step === 1) {
  return <ParentInfo formData={formData} setFormData= 
{setFormData} />;
} else {
  return <FileUpload formData={formData} setFormData= 
{setFormData} />;
}
};
return (
<div className="form">
  <h2 className="form-title">Online Application</h2>
  <div className="progressbar">
    <div
      style={{
        width: step === 0 ? "33.3%" : step === 1 ? "66.6%" : 
"100%",
      }}
    ></div>
  </div>
  <div className="form-container">
    <h1 className="form-header">{FormHeaders[step]}</h1>
    <div className="form-body">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} action="#">
        {StepDisplay()}
        <div className="form-footer">
          {step !== 0 &&
            <button className="form-btn btn" onClick={back}>
              <FaAngleLeft />
            </button>
          }
          <button className="form-btn btn" type="submit">
            {step === FormHeaders.length - 1 ? (
              <i>
                <FaRegPaperPlane />
              </i>
            ) : (
              <i>
                <FaAngleRight />
              </i>
            )}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
};

export default MultistepForm;

// File Upload 
function FileUpload({ formData, setFormData }) {
 return (
  <>
  <motion.div
    variants={slideInRight}
    initial="initial"
    whileInView="animate"
    viewport={{ once: true }}
    transition={{
      duration: 0.75,
      ease: "easeInOut",
    }} className="fields file">
    <div className="input-field field">
      <label htmlFor="#">Parent ID</label>
      <input
        required
        type="file"
        value={formData.prtIDImg}
        className="form-item"
        onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, prtIDImg: 
event.target.value 
 })
        }
      />
    </div>
    <div className="input-field field">
      <label htmlFor="#">Previous Transcript of Student</label>
      <input
        required
        type="file"
        value={formData.stdTranscript}
        className="form-item"
        onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, stdTranscript: 
event.target.value })
        }
      />
    </div>
    <div className="input-field field">
      <label htmlFor="#">Student's Biometric Photo</label>
      <input
        required
        type="file"
        value={formData.stdImg}
        className="form-item"
        onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, stdImg: event.target.value 
})
        }
      />
    </div>
  </motion.div>
</>
);
}

I am using Appwrite on the backend of my React application, and I want to upload my files to the database, that accepts the URL format of my files, but I do not know how to convert my files into a URL. All the string or integer values are being stored successfully in the database, but the files are sending an error because the format is expected to be a URL. I need help with this. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Where do the files go? It should just be path and filename.

I added the full code for context.

The form is connected to the Appwrite database. Everything is working fine, except the format of my files.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
